# Black zones when zooming in MapView

Tags: android

Im developping an Android Apps that uses google maps, and im facing some problems:

1- I want to avoid the zoom level 1 when using pinch zoom because i get something ugly it looks like this:

[image]

I can control the minimum zoom in using zoom controls by using this snippet:

```
zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            if (myMapView.getZoomLevel() == 3){
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "N other zoom levels", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            }else{
                mapController.zoomOut();
            }
        }
```

2- I want to control the maximum zoom level because im getting black zones on my screen

How can i solve these two problems, Any idea about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, you just need to override your draw method like this:

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < 1)
            mapView.getController().setZoom(2);
    }
```

Also check the max level make the need full changes.